# Как удалить куки?

Tags: php, cookie

Пробовал так, но браузер выдает ошибку. Ставлю в head.

```
<? setcookie ("de","",1); ?>
```

Может, кто подскажет, как их правильно поставить, чтобы они работали?

P.S. Раньше я их не устанавливал, но если куки с браузера не удалить, то обновленная версия сайта будет грузиться некорректно у пользователя. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php оф.доки и куча примеров

Comment: Я это прочитал. Но у меня выдает ошибку. Пишет, что данные уже пошли. А как устранить, не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы удалить куки, нужно их установить с отрицательным значением и, как уже сказали ранее, перед отправкой заголовка.    
Попробуй установить куку и сделать редирект на ту же самую страницу, примерно так:

```
setcookie ("de", "", time() - 3600);
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit();
```

**Обновление**

До первого `<html>` либо до первого `echo`, для проверки можете вставить в самый верх файла, только не забудьте добавить проверку на существования куки или другие условия, при которых будет срабатывать данный код, иначе у вас зациклится страница. )

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['de'])) { /* код выше */  }
```

Как вариант, то бишь проверяем, если стоит кука de, то удаляем ее и делает редирект.

Comment: Подскажите место, куда вставить этот код?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @zaryad68gmail, в самое-самое начало вашего кода. Понимаете, установка кук: это процедура отправки заголовков сервера к браузеру. Поэтому вызов функции setcookie должен быть до вывода любой информации

Comment: Спасибо, но как выше писал, где-то еще раньше кода идет загрузка заголовков.

    <html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    <? if (isset(... ?>
    ...
    </body>

Поправьте, может, я куки не туда ставлю?

Comment: вам нужно сделать <?php if (isset(... ?> <html> <head> ... </head> и тд

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает!

Comment: @zaryad68gmail не за что )

Answer (score 2):

> я это прочитал. но у меня выдает
> ошибку. пишет что данные уже пошли. а
> как устранить не знаю

Вся работа с куками должна проходить до отправки заголовков, или в тривиальновм случае до первого `echo`

Comment: так вот я ставил уже в самое начало. по всем правилам, но всеравно не отправляет. Скорее где-то в главе есть форма с отправкой заголовков