# cookies автозаполнение полей

Tags: php

Форма авторизации:

```
<form method="POST" action="../processes/auth_process.php">
    <input required="required" type="text" name="login" placeholder="login" value="<? if ($_COOKIE['login']) { echo $_COOKIE['login']; } ?>"><br><br>
    <input required="required" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="<? if ($_COOKIE['password']) {echo $_COOKIE['password']; } ?>"><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe">
    <label class="rememberMe">Запомнить меня</label><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Установка кукис:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['rememberMe'] ) ) {
    setcookie('login', $login, time() + 60*60*24*30*60); 
    setcookie('password', $password, time() + 60*60*24*30*60); // Установили куки на 5 лет
        // через 5 лет начиная с сейчас куки login с значением $login исчезнет
    $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login']; 
    $password_cookie = $_COOKIE['password']; 
}
```

Что не так, почему когда я выхожу с аккаунта (при выходе куки не удаляются) - при след заходе в авторизации не выводит на автозаполнение логин и пароль?
Не судите строго, я только начинающий :)

Comment: Генерировать уникальные куки не? Обнулять их тоже можно)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381436/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что не так, почему когда я выхожу с аккаунта (при выходе куки не удаляются)?

А где в коде Вы их удаляете (вы ведь ставите им хранения 5 лет)?

Пример удаления cookie:

```
unset($_COOKIE["login"]);
unset($_COOKIE["password"]);
```

Складывается впечатление, что Вы путаете $_COOKIE с $_SESSION :)

$_SESSION - удаляется при закрытии браузера.

$_COOKIE - остается в браузере, даже после закрытия браузера.

Не знаю, что Вы делаете и зачем Вам нужны $_COOKIE, но вообще в классике программирования на php для для логина и пароля используют глобальный массив $_SESSION:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

Теперь, переходя по страницам Вашего сайта, в глобальной переменной $_SESSION у вас есть значение login и password.

Хотя, вам нужно было бы туда засунуть значение пользователя после проверки по логину и паролю, что он у Вас существует на сайта.
И засунуть нечто:

```
$_SESSION['user']['login'] = $_POST['login'];
$_SESSION['user']['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['user']['birthday'] = $birthday;
```

А $_COOKIE используются немного для другого (когда нужно, что какие-то данные в переменной остались на сайте, даже после закрытия браузера. Например - подсчет числа неправильно введенных логин и/или пароль и т.д.)

Comment: Нет, в том коде я их не удаляю) Да, срок 5 лет. Я хочу именно куки, чтобы у человека при нажатии на чекбокс было автозаполнение, но они не записываются даже (только что проверил), а почему не записываются - понять не могу

Comment: какая версия php ? session_start(); добавили ?
куки в браузере можно просмотреть и украсть Ваш пароль и логин - это не безопасно.

Comment: Попробуйте еще это:  $login = $_POST['login']; session_start(); setcookie('login', $login, time() + 60*60*24*30*60);  $_COOKIE['login'] = $login;

Comment: В общем - мне лучше хранить логин и пароль пользователя в сессии?

Comment: в этот блок if ( isset($_REQUEST['rememberMe'] ) ) {   - заходит?
добавить echo 'here!';  отобразиться?  А также добавьте () вокруг time() + ... чтобы было так: setcookie('login', $_POST['login'], ( time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 60 ) );

Comment: > В общем - мне лучше хранить логин и пароль пользователя в сессии? 

у вас в коде они хешируются, потому не обязательно в сессии. В данном случае, при выборе-заполени чекбокса "запомнить меня" происходит заполение кукис. Но пользователь может их удалить в браузере.

Comment: И еще обратите внимание, что условие if ( isset($_REQUEST['rememberMe'] ) ) { - это проверка на существование переменной, но она может быть пуста, необходимо использовать:  if ( isset($_REQUEST['rememberMe']) && !empty($_REQUEST['rememberMe'])){

Comment: см. мой исходный код: нужно было вместо $login и $password _POST['login'] и пароль, как и было сказано. Но Ниже : $_POST['login'] = $_COOKIE['login'];
   $_POST['password'] = $_COOKIE['password']; И тогда все заработало)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по второму блоку вашего кода, вы сначала устанавливаете в куки пустые переменные, а потом в эти переменные записываете значения. Попробуйте поменять 2-3 строчки местами с 5-6.

Comment: неа( поменял ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```
setcookie('login', $_POST['login'], time() + 60*60*24*30*60); 
setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], time() + 60*60*24*30*60);
```

Comment: Не хочет, пробовал. Если есть ссылки на то, где люди пишут или написан код по автозаполнению с помощью куки - буду рад!

Comment: Cookies точно сохраняются?

Comment: Нет! Только что сделал else echo "Куки не сохранены" и выдает, что не сохранены.. Вместо $login $password я сделал $_POST['login'], $_POST['password'].

Comment: Нужно больше кода. Возможно ты не задал область для куки, попробуй так: setcookie('login', $_POST['login'], time() + 60*60*24*30*60, "/");

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey995/mvgxjfo4/2/